# How adblock plus hides elements?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, adblock

I try to understand how adblock hides elements. I only see something like that `-moz-binding: url("about:abp-elemhidehit?067696143543#dummy") !important;`. And this binding is empty. I look in sources and see `AboutHandler` that intercept `abp-elemhidehit?(Math.Random)`, But it looks like the fact that this class simply counts the number of hits in the filter. How -moz-binding can hide node?

Comment: i thought it gave them a unique class name and that class was just set to `display:none`

Comment: i don't see any changes in classes, also i don't see display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`open` method of the `HitRegistrationChannel`](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockplus/blob/master/lib/elemHideHitRegistration.js#L127) returns `<bindings xmlns='http://www.mozilla.org/xbl'><binding id='dummy'/></bindings>` on a miss and `<bindings xmlns='http://www.mozilla.org/xbl'/>` on a hit.

The former seems neutral and unobtrusive. But the latter has the effect of `display:none`.

I don't know what's the benefit of this approach, but it works.

edit: Probably untrusted code can modify css properties but not `-moz-binding`

Comment: Where the display:none effect is setting on <bindings xmlns='http://www.mozilla.org/xbl'/>?

Comment: Very nice investigation man this is an interesting note (about latter being non-overridable by untrusted) too I'm bookmarking this.

Comment: @Suhan I don't understand your question, could you rephrase please?

Comment: @paa I just don't understand why <bindings xmlns='mozilla.org/xbl'/> have display:none effect)

Comment: The only way I could effectively change the -moz-binding is to delete and then recreate the element (as documented by Mozilla). Also see this related bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163023